# Using values of table in the WHERE clause of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with descriptions of a lot of companies.

```
TABLE dbo.[TblCompanies]
(
    [CompanyID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyProfile] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
)
```

Descriptions look like that

> "Agilent Technologies, Inc. provides application focused solutions to
>   .."

I also have another table that has some strings

```
TABLE dbo.[TblFilter]
    (
        [Pattern] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
    )
```

For example

> technology
>
> applications

How can I get `CompanyIDs` of a all the companies that have **ALL** the values that are in `TblFilter` in their `CompanyProfile`? The appearing order of the filter strings in `CompanyProfile` **IS NOT** important. What **IS** important is that **ALL** these strings will be in the `CompanyProfile`.

Would be prefer solution without cursors.

Thanks.

Comment: `Technologies <> technology`, `application <> applications`

Comment: You're right, but currently I need exact matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter out rows for which any pattern does not match:

```
select  *
from    TblCompanies c
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    TblFilter f
        where   c. CompanyProfile not like '%' + f.Pattern + '%'
        )
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this

I hope I got this right finally:

Any match will count as `1`. The `SUM` of these values must be equal to the count in table `pattern`

```
DECLARE @companies TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourText VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @companies VALUES
 ('This contains abc and xyz')
,('This contains mno')
,('This contains abc and xyz and mno')
,('This contains nothing')
,('This contains abc');

DECLARE @pattern TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourPattern VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @pattern VALUES
 ('abc')
--,('def')
,('xyz');

SELECT c.ID,c.YourText
FROM @companies AS c
CROSS JOIN @pattern AS p
GROUP BY c.ID,c.YourText
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.YourText LIKE '%' + p.YourPattern + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @pattern)
```

Comment: Will not work for this `INSERT INTO @pattern VALUES  ('abc'),('xyz'),('yz');`

Comment: @AlexK, Might be I'm missing something, but this should work. The `CROSS JOIN` returns all combinations, the count should be correct. But anyway the accepted answer is way better :-)

Comment: Problem not in CROSS JOIN but in LIKE. 'xyz' contains 'yz' and this causes erroneous condition.

Comment: @AlexK, well, no... This depends... We don't know if the OP wants to deal with overlapping patterns somehow differently... The OP just statet: *ALL these strings will be in the CompanyProfile*...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into creating a `Full Text Index`, as explained here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142497.aspx and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx

In short:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FTCat;  
GO

-- There has to be a unique key for the Full Text Search to identify the row
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_CompanyID ON dbo.TblCompanies(CompanyID);  
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.TblCompanies  
(  
    CompanyProfile                --Full-text index column name  
    Language 2057                 --2057 is the LCID for British English  
)  
KEY INDEX ui_CompanyID ON FTCat      --Unique index  
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO            --Population type;  
GO
```

Which you can then query with either `FREETEXT` or `CONTAINS`:

```
SELECT CompanyID
      ,CompanyProfile
FROM dbo.TblCompanies 
WHERE CONTAINS(CompanyProfile, 'technology AND applications')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this way:

```
select * from @companies c where exists (select 1 from @pattern p where c.YourText like concat('%',p.YourPattern,'%'))
```